# Click to hide any elements

Tags: javascript

I am just trying to code some simple javascript code to hide any elements in webpage which I click.I am going to use this code as bookmark or in console.

I have written below code so far

```
var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.myelement');

Array.from(deleteLinks).forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
console.log("hi");
             event.preventDefault();
this.remove();

    });
});
```

What above code does is when I click any element it just hide it.But I need to do following things.

- I need to preventDefault on all the element which I click.`(In my
     case my code works only when I click class .myelement)`

  - When I have multiple element with same class or ID ,, all should be hidden or removed

I tried below code , but it gets body class name, How to get the current element classname.

```
var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('body');

Array.from(deleteLinks).forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
console.log(this.className);

    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('body');"? Why you taking body here?

Comment: Try with `document.querySelectorAll('*')`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat : It prevents ... when did I tell so

Comment: @Hanif : I just tried to capture any clicks inside body and get its classname

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan : its getting classname of all , I just need to get classname of element i click and hide or remove it all

Comment: sounds a bit like the uBlock origin element picker

Comment: @Vishnu do you think it work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/3fgc5uhv/9/

Comment: @Hanif : Almost , but When I click that elements ,, all the elements with same class selector should be removed, but now only that particular is getting removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working sample.

Code Snippet

```
var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('body *');

Array.from(deleteLinks).forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if(this.className != '') {
            var combineClassNames = this.className.replace(' ', '.');
            var links = document.querySelectorAll('.' + combineClassNames);

            Array.from(links).forEach(inner => {
                inner.remove();
            });
        }
        else {
            this.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/3fgc5uhv/5/

Comment: Hi , Try your code at stackoverflow console..When I click add comment button ..its closing all

Comment: @Vishnu, check this in fiddle shared in the answer.

Comment: Yea I checked but its not working when there is multiple class... , but I am trying to use this code on any web page..check this .. https://jsfiddle.net/3fgc5uhv/3/

Comment: Hi , thanks for your time , your solution works for simple page , I am trying to implement this in real time website... please check this out https://jsfiddle.net/3fgc5uhv/8/ click on image or 1st link

Comment: @Vishnu, this is just an example of what has been asked. You could take this as a reference and modify it as per your needs.